# Find by property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I have defined a moogoose schema as follows:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    google: Object,
    github: Object,
    linkedin: Object,
    facebook: Object,
    microsoft: Object,
    twitter: Object
});
```

All these properties are supposed to contain a sub-property `id`. So given a `profile` sent by a `loginSuccessfully`, I want to find the document whose `id` (according to `profile.provider`) matches `profile.id`.

But, the traditional `.find({ "...": profile.id }, (err, users) => ... )` could not express this dynamic case of `profile.provider`.

Does anyone know how to write this mongoose query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find the id across all providers, you can use `$or`:

```
.find(
    { $or: ["google", "github", "linkedin", "facebook", "microsoft", "twitter"].map(p=>({[p + ".id"]: profile.id})) }, 
    (err, users) => ... 
)
```

For a single known provider it is the *traditional*:

```
.find(
    { [provider + ".id"]: profile.id }, 
    (err, users) => ... 
)
```